# After updating Ubuntu, Postfix fails

Tags: updates, postfix

I am complete new here.
I have updated and ubuntu v. 16.04.7 LTS to 18.04.6 LTS.
The server is only used for mail sending.
After that, postfix is complaining "host or domaine name not found"^
MX Host not found.

Can I get some advice ?

Regards Steen

Comment: Welcome. You might have noticed you have 7 days left to update Ubuntu 18 until it's out of support as well. Depending on your scenario, it might be more hassle-free to install Ubuntu 22.04 and configure Postfix again (you can always build upon the previous config).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you answer, but I'm really lost here.
I have to get it up running as fast as possible. It is in production and a lot of mails waiting to be sent.

Comment: I'm sorry for your situation, but you really can't expect that a volunteer community can save anyone from poor planning. Maybe someone can come up with a magic solution, maybe not. I'm just trying to reason about what might be most feasible in the long run. And running software that's out of support is not on that list ...

Comment: Under any circumstance, you should probably add more detail to your question, like log output etc. if anyone should be able to help out. Right now, there isn't much to go with.

Comment: OK, I will try to figure out, how to uploade logs.

Comment: I think my issue is related to DNS.

Comment: You're probably right. [This might help troubleshooting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282966/postfix-mx-host-not-found).

Comment: It was a problem with the DNS.
I edited the /etc/resolv.conf file. I added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
I am aware of the version. That was the purpose with the update.
I will update to newer version later :-)

Comment: Many thanks for yous answers.
It really helped me.

Comment: I upgraded from 16.04.7 LTS to 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: Done. Ubuntu/postfix is new to me.
I'm learning.

Comment: Well done, and if you can find another minute, perhaps answer your own question with what you did exactly to solve the problem, so others may find your solution (and upvote it :-));

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the DNS. Editing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 fixed the issue.